# Find a 2nd set of digit in a string(SQL/PL-SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a string which may be of below types

```
string          expected result
15-th-rp         15
15/12-rp         12
15-12-th         12
4-5-6            5
```

Now i have to find the digit, 
1)  If a string contains only 1digit set then same will be displayed. 
2) If there are multiple set of digits between character then i have to find the 2nd set of digit. Please help me.

```
  with a as (
   select '15-th-rp' as data from dual
   union all
   select  '15/12-rp' from dual
   union all
   select  '15-12-th' from dual
   union  all
   select '4-5-6' from dual
  )
  select regexp_substr(data,'[0-9]+',REGEXP_INSTR(data,'[/|-]')+1) from a;
```

Comment: Probably want to use regular expressions ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm ).  To help work out what regular expression you want, can your string ever *start* with a non-numeric character?  And, if so, does the subsequent numeric expression count as the first or second occurence?

Comment: I have tried this query. But I am not able to resolve my first question.

Comment: with a as (
       select '15-th-rp' as data from dual
       union all
       select  '15/12-rp' from dual
       union all
       select  '15-12-th' from dual
       union  all
       select '4-5-6' from dual
      )
      select regexp_substr(data,'[0-9]+',REGEXP_INSTR(data,'[/|-]')+1) from a;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
with a as (select '15-th-rp' data from dual union all
           select '15/12-rp' data from dual union all
           select '15-12-th' data from dual union all
           select '4-5-6' data from dual)
select data,
       coalesce(regexp_substr(data,'[0-9]+',1,2),
                regexp_substr(data,'[0-9]+',1,1)) extracted_data
from   a;

DATA     EXTRACTED_DATA
-------- --------------
15-th-rp 15            
15/12-rp 12            
15-12-th 12            
4-5-6    5
```

The good thing about using COALESCE is that it won't evaluate the second (and subsequent) arguments unless they're required.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't answer the question about whether `'_1_2'` should return `1` or `2`, so I'm assuming you'd want `1`.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[0-9]+', REGEXP_INSTR(data, '[^0-9][0-9]')+1)
```

A somewhat hacky way to get `2` from `_1_2` *(whilst also coping with `_1` yielding `1`)* could be...

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(data || '_' || data, '[0-9]+', 1, 2)
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a54bb/7

Answer (score 0):

Do it in 2 steps. First match the first and second occurences of the pattern and then show the first set only if there is no second set (i.e. it's null).

```
with
a(data) as (
  select '15-th-rp' from dual union all
  select '15/12-rp' from dual union all
  select '15-12-th' from dual union all
  select '4-5-6' from dual
),
b(data, first, second) as (
  select
   data
  ,regexp_substr(data, '[[:digit:]]+')
  ,regexp_substr(data, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, 2)
  from a
)
select data, nvl(second, first) as result from b;
```

Returns result:

```
DATA     RESULT
-------- ------
15-th-rp 15
15/12-rp 12
15-12-th 12
4-5-6    5
```

Comment: Ooooh, what's the difference between `[0-9]` and `[[:digit:]]`?

Comment: `[:digit:]` is a [POSIX character class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) supported by Oracle. The other POSIX character classes are handier than this one.